# How to inject interop objects from third party library using "Autofac"

Tags: c#, oop, interface, com, autofac

Third party software provided the library entitled `ProxyGW`

Here is their interface code

```
public interface ProxyGW : IProxyGW10, _ProxyGWEvents_Event
{
}
```

Here is interface `_ProxyGWEvents_Event`

```
public interface _ProxyGWEvents_Event
{
    event _ProxyGWEvents_onConnectSucceededEventHandler onConnectSucceeded;
}
```

Here is `IProxyGW10` interface,  goes on 8,7,6....interfaces!

```
public interface IProxyGW10 : IProxyGW9
{}
```

I am using `Autofac` to get the dependency Injection power. I have written as class `ProxyGWModule` to register the component

```
using Autofac;
using ProxyGWLib;

public class ProxyGWModule: Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Register(ProxyGW);// I get error here
    }
}
```

**Error**

> 'ProxyGW' is a type, which is not valid in the given context ProxyGWModule.cs

Error goes if I do like this

```
 ProxyGW proxygw = new ProxyGW();
 builder.RegisterInstance(proxygw).As<IProxyGW10>(); //which interface shall be part of
```

Is it the right way? if yes, what happens to `_ProxyGWEvents_Event` interface? I want to have access to all the events in `_ProxyGWEvents_Event`

**I tried as below**

```
 builder.RegisterInstance(ProxyGWClass);
```

Error

> Interop type 'ProxyGWClass' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead. ProxyGWModule.cs

Root class is like this below. IProxyGW9, IProxyGW8.....are different versions. Obviously we use only one among them.

```
 public class ProxyGWClass : IProxyGW10, ProxyGW, _ProxyGWEvents_Event, IProxyGW9, IProxyGW8, IProxyGW7, IProxyGW6, IProxyGW5, IProxyGW4, IProxyGW3, IProxyGW2 {}
```

So, below is not showing any error

```
 ProxyGW proxygw = new ProxyGW();
 builder.RegisterInstance(proxygw).As<IProxyGW9>().As<_ProxyGWEvents_Event>();
```

Comment: ProxyGW is an interface. You need a class that implements that interface.

Comment: ProxyGWClass - this is the class - I get this error - Interop type 'ProxyGWClass' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead. ProxyGWModule.cs

Comment: Oh, that is a COM interface ... this needs Hans Passant.

Comment: `builder.RegisterInstance(proxygw).As<IProxyGW10>().As<_ProxyGWEvents_Event>();`

Comment: yes it's COM interface

Comment: please see the updated question: root class has so many interfaces!

Comment: How to tag @Hans Passant.   :)

Comment: @Johnny you are right! let me test and keep you posted.